# Unable to load dynamic library php_sqlsrv_7_nts.dll is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: php-7

Thought I'd see if there were any sql server drivers for php 7.  Another question on Stack Overflow pointed me to these drivers [here](https://github.com/Azure/msphpsql/releases/tag/v4.0.0)

So I install php_sqlsrv_7_nts.dll into my ext folder and add the following line to my php.ini:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts.dll
```

I get this warning on every php script I run:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php7\ext\php_sqlsrv_7_nts.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I realise this is just a pre-release version and there are many things to iron out still, but I was hoping to at least do some basic things.

What am I doing wrong, or do I need to wait a bit more for a better release.

Some info that might be useful:

```
PHP Version => 7.0.5

System => Windows NT GB275L-I-T-5654 6.3 build 9600 (Windows 8.1 Professional Edition) i586
Build Date => Mar 30 2016 09:57:56
Compiler => MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015)
Architecture => x86
Configure Command => cscript /nologo configure.js  "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--disable-zts" "--with-pdo-oci=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-12c=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--without-analyzer" "--with-pgo"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally got this solved.  Needed to install some more things before it would work, namely:

1. Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86) which you can get from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)
2. The ODBC drivers which you can get from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434)

Answer (score 6):

It works for me.

1.Download the extension windows 7.0
https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases

2.And then according to the system requirement paste it in ext folder.
Note: Paste only the thread safe version  (php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts.dll , php_sqlsrv_7_ts.dll)

3.And edit the php.ini file add this extension to your php.ini file and restart and check

Comment: just to note: there will be x64 & x86 dirs. On Win 10 I use x86; just be sure to know or try the different versions

Answer (score 0):

The extension file from [Github MSPHPSQL releases](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases) did not work for me and gave me the same predicament with the OP. I went to this [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) which gave me the [driver (extension) for MSSQL Server](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2120362), go ahead and install it on a directory you can easily find, in my case I saved it in my `c:\mssql-driver` then inside get the extension (DLL) file that fits your OS and PHP version, in my case since I am using **PHP 7.2.x and x64 Windows** I picked the following file and put it in my PHP extension directory `c:\xampp\php\ext`:

1. php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll
2. php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll

and in my `php.ini` located in `c:\xampp\php\php.ini` defined it under the Dynamic Extensions section:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
...
extension=curl
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll
...
```

Answer (score 0):

delete the "php_" on "php_sqlsrv_7_nts". just write "sqlsrv_7_nts"