# Unable to load dynamic library php_sqlsrv on easyphp

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, odbc, easyphp

I'm trying to install the SQL server extension for PHP, but the extension is not visible in phpinfo().

I'm on windows 10 with easyPHP,
I installed ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server.

My error log of apache

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\\eds-binaries\\php\\php713vc14x86x170919113050\\ext\\php_sqlsrv_71_nts_x86.dll' - Le module sp\xef\xbf\xbdcifi\xef\xbf\xbd est introuvable.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
[Mon Nov 06 11:47:53.108947 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8260:tid 664] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you checked that the file exists in that path?

Comment: Yes the file exist in that path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to load dynamic library php\_sqlsrv\_7\_nts.dll is not a valid Win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36593213/1255289)

Comment: ODBC drivers and Visual C++ Redistributable 2015 are installed, I think the issue doesn't come from that

Comment: sp\xef\xbf\xbdcifi\xef\xbf\xbd decoded : spécifié