# Using WAMP to connect to SQL Server

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I've read a [lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015179/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect) [of](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/191) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776078/cannot-call-function-sqlsrv-connect) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859989/call-to-undefined-function-odbc-connect-message-while-connecting-sap-hana-data/17861394#17861394) on this problem, but I think mine is a little different because the output I'm getting doesn't match what others have had.

I am running WampServer Version 3.1.4 64bit and trying to connect to a SQL Server DB and I get the following error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()`
using the following code:

```
$serverName = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$connectionInfo = array("Database" => "db_name", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"db_pwd");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

I have tried the following:

- I downloaded the sql drivers for PHP 7 and 7.1 and tried them with the corresponding PHP versions
- I made sure to restart all services after updating the php.ini file.
- With my version of WAMP the php.ini file in the Apache folder is just a shortcut to `phpForApache.ini` in the `php7.1.22` folder and it updates automatically.
- The extensions DO show up in the WAMP menu: `PHP > PHP extensions`
  and they have the green check mark next to them

I consistently get the following in my php_error.log:

```
[27-Nov-2018 14:25:16 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.1.22/ext/php_sqlsrv_71_nts.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
 in Unknown on line 0
[27-Nov-2018 14:25:16 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.1.22/ext/php_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
 in Unknown on line 0
```

As stated, I've tried using the appropriate dlls for both php 7 and 7.1.22 and got the same output:

```
[27-Nov-2018 15:12:37 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.32/ext/php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

 in Unknown on line 0

[27-Nov-2018 15:12:37 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.32/ext/php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x86.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I'm really not sure what other config I must be missing. I also tried the x64 versions, but I get an error stating the file could not be found, even though I triple checked the location.

Seeing as I get the same `not a valid Win32 application` error for both versions, I guess it's something outside of PHP

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36593213/unable-to-load-dynamic-library-php-sqlsrv-7-nts-dll-is-not-a-valid-win32-applica, you may be missing the Visual C++ 2015 Runtime and ODBC drivers.  Can you verify that the pre-requisites have been installed?

Comment: yes - I tried installing the Visual C++ Redistributable and and windows told me it was already installed

Comment: You mentioned that you are running the 64-bit version of WAMP, however it appears that the sqlsrv drivers are 32-bit and failing to load in a 64-bit context.  Try either switching to a 32-bit WAMP, or else find a 64-bit version of the sqlsrv drivers (see: http://robsphp.blogspot.com/2012/06/unofficial-microsoft-sql-server-driver.html)

Comment: I just checked the installed versions and I have 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013 and 2017. Some are x86, but most are x64

Comment: I've tried both 32 and 64 bit versions of the sql drivers. With the 64 bit versions, I got a "file not found" error in my php error log