# Unable to load dynamic library php_sqlsrv_73_nts_x86.dll is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: sqlsrv, php-7.3

So I install `php_sqlsrv_73_nts_x86.dll` and `php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts_x86.dll` into my ext folder and add the following line to my php.ini:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_73_nts_x86.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts_x86.dll
```

I get this warning on every php script I run:

```
Unable to load dynamic library 'php_sqlsrv_73_nts_x86' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_73_nts_x86 (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.)
 PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts_x86' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts_x86 (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Some additional info;

```
PHP Version = 7.3.2,
System = Windows 10,
Architecture = x86,
```

And I have referred to this [Unable to load dynamic library php_sqlsrv_7_nts.dll is not a valid Win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36593213/unable-to-load-dynamic-library-php-sqlsrv-7-nts-dll-is-not-a-valid-win32-applica) but it didnt help me

Edit 1, I have tried removing the _x86 tag in my extension as well, but that did not help me at all.

Answer (score 1):

So after tinkering with this for a few hours, I found out that by reinstalling a 64bit XAMPP and using `php_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64.dll and php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64.dll` worked for me. Im not sure as to why, but I guess that's a solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

i use like you and i also have errors
but when use ts version like :
php_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll and php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dl
and i have not any error.